# how to create a list that can get element in list by for loop

Tags: python-3.x, list

Here is my code.

I want to do a for loop way that makes every element into a new variable called list_range. However, the question is that it merely adds the last elements of for loop structure. **My purpose is to add every element in list_range**. like this.

```
wb = xw.Book("C:/Users/六神/Desktop/busch.xlsx")  # Connect existing excel

sht = wb.sheets(1)

for i in range(2, 10):
    i = str(i)
    list_y =[sht.range("F" + i).value, sht.range("C" + i).value,sht.range("E" + i).value]
    list_Range=[]
    list_Range.extend(list_y)   #My hope is that list_Range[[v],[v],[v] and so on]

list_range = [[v]]  # In practice
```

Comment: What is sht here? Can you also provide sample input and output

Comment: I've edited it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want `list_Range` to be a `list` of `list`s.

You need to move `list_Range=[]` out of the body of the `for` loop, or `list_Range` will just reset to an empty `list` each iteration.

Instead of calling the `extend()` method, you want to call the `append()` method. `extend()` takes an *iterable* (such as a list) and adds each item onto the list, separately. `append()` adds the entire argument to the list (in your case, a list with 3 items).

```
wb = xw.Book("C:/Users/六神/Desktop/busch.xlsx")  # Connect existing excel

sht = wb.sheets(1)

list_Range=[]
for i in range(2, 10):
    i = str(i)
    list_y =[sht.range("F" + i).value, sht.range("C" + i).value,sht.range("E" + i).value]
    list_Range.extend(list_y)   #My hope is that list_Range[[v],[v],[v] and so on]
```

Comment: No worries! Don't forget to vote up or accept the answer if you want, as per [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)